# Launch an opaque fragment

Tags: android

From an activity is launched a fragment by push a button. This fragment is showed but also is showed and content of activity from witch is launched. I want that fragment to be opaque.

```
launchFragmentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            DisplayFragment fragmentDisplay = new DisplayFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.display_container, fragmentDisplay);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: What do you return in `onCreateView()` of your `DisplayFragment`?

Comment: A fragment is part of an activity and cannot exist without one..Kindly expound on what you mean by opaque..

Comment: @Bmbariah Yes, I omitted that because I guess that is obviously.

Answer (score 0):

in your fragment layout.xml file set the background to your parent node. like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    <!-- set here your background -->
    android:background="@color/main_bg"
    tools:context="fragmentsMain.HomeFragment">

</RelativeLayout >
```

Comment: Its depend what is alpha for ARGB.